# How to play Spotify music on Sonos using the Sonos API

Tags: spotify, sonos

Is there a way to play a certain album or artist from spotify using the Sonos API?

I managed to play the favorites from Sonos, but I'd like to play any song from Spotify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We don’t support browse or playback of specific partner content through the Sonos Sound Platform. Favorites and Playlists support is intended to help you get content started in a Sonos group.

Comment: Is this answer still valid?

Answer (score -2):

You can download your Spotify music with TunePat Spotify Converter and then transfer them to your Sonos.